# iOS AdHoc Distribution with new UDIDs

Tags: ios, adhoc

I have new devices and added the UDID to my developer account. 
After that, all my provisioning is automatically handle by Xcode. However, I found that the new devices cannot use my newly compiled apps. It seems that the UDID is not in the corresponding provisioning profile. However, as it is manage by Xcode, i do not know where can I update it. And the Xcode used provisioning file name also cannot be seen in my account. What can be go wrong here? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to https://developer.apple.com/membercenter, select your team on the top right, and then Certifcates, Identifiers & Profiles. First, add your new device under Devices and then add that device under Provisioning Profiles —> All. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I have added the devices into the list already. However, when i let Xcode to automatically manage the certificates, it say that it use iOS Team Provisioning Profile --- I don't know where i can find this, and when I open the provisioning profile on my Mac, I found that does not include the newly added UDID (added at the portal), so my question is how Xcode choose which Provisioning profile to use, and how can I update it?